# slide_level issue with Rmarkdown with slidy output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, slidy

In the following code, I should see 2 slides, the first slide should have title List of items and the second slide should start at Second heading.
But I only see one slide after the first page. Where do I misunderstand?

```
---
title: Issue in setting slide level
date: December 3, 2019
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
---

# List of items.

 - One
 - Two
 - Three

## Second Heading

### Third Heading
```

I got it working using this :

```
---
title: "Issue in setting slide level"
date: "December 9, 2019"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    pandoc_args:
      - --slide-level
      - 2
---
```

Can someone confirm if slide_level argument is not supported for slidy slideshows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `slide_level` was not an argument of `rmarkdown::slidy_presentation`. [I just added it](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/07b238ceee3aa428acdfbb7351c1cfd9ae48e3f7) to the development version of **rmarkdown**. You may try it with

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```